# How to Set a Secret in GitHub Workflow that is Injected into Properties File that is Not in the Workflow Folder

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions, github-secret

I have a .github/workflow .yml file that I am using as a GitHub Action workflow.

Please bear with me I am new to GitHub.

I am working on a project to trigger a build in GitHub whenever a file in the project is changed.  I have that part working.  However, I was told that we shouldn't have any files that contain username/passwords, and that we should replace them with GitHub secrets.  I read somewhere that GitHub secrets only work on files in .github/workflow directory.  Unfortunately, the username/passwords I know about are in .properties files, in a different directory than .github/workflow.  Is there a way to inject GitHub secrets into a file not found in .github/workflow?

Some possible approaches:

1. In the build.yml file, I can set a global environment variable equal to the GitHub secret, then use the environment variable in the .properties file (eg: ${{env.mypassword}}).  That hasn't worked for me.
2. I could call a bash script in the build.yml file to take as input the secret, and then the bash script could proceed to append the .properties file with the input.  The secret would be available to the bash script since its called within the build.yml file, in the .github/workflow file, in the same shell.  I haven't tried this yet.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can inject with env and then send to your bash script as you said.

- example:

```yaml
    - name: push change
      env:
        GITHUB_LOGIN: xxx
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: |
        git push https://$GITHUB_LOGIN:$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY.git master:master
```

also, create github actions is on the location:

`repo -> settings/secrets/actions`